# IntelliSense: expression must have class type (prefix postfix error)

Tags: c++

so I have a interval class with two numbers, and I want to use ++ prefix and postfix, but I get the error:      1   IntelliSense: expression must have class type

here is the code:

```
class intervallum
{
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    intervallum();
    intervallum(int x,int y);
    intervallum operator++();
    void operator++(int);
    void kiir();
};

intervallum intervallum::operator++()
{
    a -= 1;
    b += 1;
    return intervallum(a,b);
}

void intervallum::operator++(int)
{ 
    operator++();
}

void intervallum::kiir()
{
    cout << "[" << a << "," << b << "]" << endl;
}

void main()
{
    intervallum i(2,4);
    i.kiir();
    (++i).kiir();
    i.kiir();
    (i++).kiir; // <- the error is with this
    i.kiir();
}
```

Comment: `intervallum operator++();` should return a reference `intervallum&`. And `void operator++(int);` should return `intervallum`.

Comment: Thank you for the helps! I got what I did wrong, had to change void operator++(int) to intervallum operator++(int) and this way works properly how I imagined :)

Comment: @user3520631 The SO philosophy is to reward users for their help. The way you do this is by *upvoting* answers (triangle-like button above the number). You can also *accept* an answer, which means it was the one that helped you the most. Which one is usually not a big deal.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I think `void operator++(int)` should more correctly return nothing... At least unless you rename it to `intervallum operator++(int)`...

Comment: @twalberg Of course. I just used the function signature from the post so OP would know which `operator++` I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the expression

```
(i++).kiir;
```

First, it should be `(i++).kiir();`, right? Even so, `intervallum::operator++(int)` returns `void`, and you're trying to invoke `kiir` over a `void` object (if such thing exists). Not good.

There are a couple of things to notice:

- As suggested in the comments, `intervallum::operator++()` should return a reference to the object being acted upon, otherwise you'll end up working with a copy.
- You should **really** say to the compiler that `main` returns an `int`, even though you don't.

Comment: Thank you for the helps! I got what I did wrong, had to change void operator++(int) to intervallum operator++(int)

Answer (score 0):

You must read compiler output, not intellisense stuff. Compiler explicitly states a problem:

```
main.cpp(38): error C2228: left of '.kiir' must have class/struct/union
              type is 'void'
```

Then you go to a line indicated (38 in my example), right-click on `i++`, choose "Go to definition" and see that your method really returns `void`.

You will probably need to check operator signatures list to write a rigth one: 
[Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: Thank you for the helps! I got what I did wrong, had to change
void operator++(int) to intervallum operator++(int)